# from where can I download sun and moon upstate and downstate info

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing, xmlhttprequest

I find this [msn page](http://www.msn.com/en-us/weather/today/K'alak'i-T'bilisi,Georgia/we-city-41.717,44.833?iso=GE&form=PRWLAS&q=K%27alak%27i%20T%27bilisi)

Here, in the details tab is the information when the sun and the moon rises and sets.

I would like to parse this info, but I can not find the link where this page is sending  the `XMLHTTPREQUEST`.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: post some code first .. something you have tried

Answer (score 0):

I found very good library in js
[sun/moon rises time calculator and js renderer](https://github.com/mourner/suncalc)